# One mutable borrowing or many immutable borrowings in Rust...why?

Tags: rust

Why does Rust allow only one mutable borrowing or many immutable borrowings? Can its behavior be useful for preventing from bug-prone codes even in single-threaded programming? If it is, what is an example case?

Comment: https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2015/05/17/the-problem-with-shared-mutability/

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this helps prevent bugs in single-threaded cases.  Consider this simple case:

```
let a = vec![1i32];

let b = &a[0]; // Borrows the first element of the Vec.

a.clear();

println!("{}", b); // Oops, the value b references doesn't exist anymore!
```

This fails to compile in Rust because `a.clear()` requires mutably borrowing `a`, but `b` is immutably borrowing it.  Equivalent code would compile in C++ using `std::vector`, but would exhibit undefined behavior at runtime.  (It's a common misconception that there's a problem with Rust when it rejects rewritten code from other languages like C++ where the original code compiled fine in that language, when, in fact, there was likely a memory safety issue in the original code that was undiscovered.)

Note that even `a.push()` could invalidate references obtained prior because it can require reallocating storage for the vec if the internal allocation has no more free capacity.

Mutably borrowing a value must exclude any other overlapping borrow because mutating a value can result in the invalidation of overlapping borrows of the same value.